# Entity Framework Windows App

Tags: c#, entity-framework, c#-4.0

I have EF application with following code.

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace WinFormswithEFSample
{
public class ObservableListSource<T> : ObservableCollection<T>, IListSource
where T : class
{
    private IBindingList _bindingList;

    bool IListSource.ContainsListCollection { get { return false; } }

    IList IListSource.GetList()
    {
        return _bindingList ?? (_bindingList = this.ToBindingList());
    }
} 
}
```

But when build the project attached error comming. What is the error in this code?[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try add namespace `System.Data.Entity` which resides in `EntityFramework.dll` library (this assembly is necessery).